# Colorbox JQuery Can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm working with colorbox for the first time and I need some help. I have the files in the right folder. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

 <link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

</head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<body>
<!--JQuery library-->
<a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      var foo = "bar";
    </script>


<!--Colorbox Call-->



        <a class='gallery'     href='images/DSC_0114.JPG'>Photo_1</a>
        <a class='gallery'     href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_2</a>
        <a class='gallery'     href='images/money2.jpg'>Photo_3</a>

        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox();
            });;
        </script>

</body>
```

Content for  class "box" id "box" Goes Here

I'm a beginner so please point out everything you think of! =)

Comment: @ocanal here is a new thread with the code that I'm working on. Do you see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

You're loading colorbox before you load jquery. It needs to be the other way around.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay @Adam Merrifield I put <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      var foo = "bar";
    </script>

Comment: before  <link href="colorbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Comment: @EmilyMagnuson It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/cJkGK/ (obviously it doesn't look perfect because the image files aren't linked correctly, and I don't suggest to use github as a CDN)

Comment: the code you gave me is not in HTML with a <head> and a <body>, so I don't know where to put it. Could you please elaborate on these points. And when you click on an image link in the JSFiddle, it doesn't open up the image how it's supposed to, so how do you do that?